# Electrostatic force question on the formula distance power

Tags: electromagnetism

I am a student and as far as I am concerned the formula of the electrostatic force looks like this : F = k*q1*q2/r^2

The thing is that my teacher made a change to the formula for the sake of an exercise and converted r^2 to an r^3 and I cant understand why .

Comment: There is just no way we can possibly know what your instructor meant.

Comment: if I add the exercise as a photo ?

Comment: More than adding photos, it would be useful if you try to reconstruct the context of that manipulation. I can easily figure out some good reason for it. But it would be pointless to try to guess something that you could easily ask your teacher.

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher probably wrote it this way

$$\vec{F}=\frac{kq_1q_2\vec{r}}{r^3}$$

instead of this way

$$\vec{F}=\frac{kq_1q_2\hat{r}}{r^2}.$$

The denominator has a cube when the numerator has the entire position vector rather than a unit vector.